# showing an expression involving a symmetric matrix equals its determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $M$ be a symmetric real matrix $(n+1)$ by $(n+1)$.
Let the $n$ by $n$ top left corner matrix be $A$ and denote $c$ to be the column vector with $n$ entries and the $(n+1, n+1)$ of $M$ to be $x$, so that
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} A && c \\ c^T && x   \end{bmatrix}. 
$$
We know that the $\det A \neq 0$.

I want to show (I think this is true!) that
$$
x - c^T A^{-1} c  = \frac{\det M}{\det A}. 
$$

For $n=1$, it is easy enough to check the statement is true.
If someone could have any idea on how I can prove this, it would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: It seems that the expression in question is a special case of the so-called Schur complement (it often arises when one needs to compute the inverse of a matrix with block structure). See e.g. here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement. In particular, your identity follows from the LDU-decomposition (see section "Background" in Wiki). Of course, this is more or less the same what you described in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

My neighbour showed me a nice answer so I decided to post it here.
First notice that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A^{-1} && 0 \\ 0 && 1   \end{bmatrix} M = \begin{bmatrix} I && A^{-1} c \\ c^T && x   \end{bmatrix}.   
$$
If we row deduce the last matrix we can get
$$
\begin{bmatrix} I && A^{-1} c \\ 0 && x - c^T A^{-1} c  \end{bmatrix}.   
$$
Thus taking the determinant of both sides, taking into account the row reduction we get
$$
\det M/\det A = x - c^T A^{-1} c.
$$